# Send mass email through Salesforce

Tags: email, amazon

What is a good option for sending 200.000+ emails a month over Salesforce? Ideally we want to use an emailer like Amazon SES or SendGrid. The problem is that reading their API you are forced to do 1 call per email sent (as much as I understand from their WEB API). I'm not sure, they do let you send over 10.000 address the same email but it needs to be unique and we do have some minimal personalization (field merge) for the emails.
There is an [app](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000005uxj5EAA) for SendGrid on Salesforce, but it's not officially listed and installing it in a dev org it looked buggy (I haven't been able to make it recognize my SendGrid account).

So, what are the available options to send mass transactional email through Salesforce? Am I wrong in the restrictions I'm seeing in these two examples for the API?

Thanks

Comment: As an FYI, my organization used SendGrid for years but then invested time and resources to switch to Amazon SES because of the cost difference between the two. Amazon is significantly cheaper.

Comment: We used the bulk send API from SendGrid and it worked well for sending a lot of emails at once.

Comment: @RohitKunal Can you shed more light on the steps/implementation of Sendgrid with SF? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, what we end up using and worked quite well was MailUp. It has an App (also unlisted, [here](http://help.mailup.com/display/mailupUserGuide/Salesforce+connector%3A+installing) is the installation guide). It has it's perks but it was rather powerful, meeting all our critical requirements, while using mostly the MailUp platform and synching information back into SFDC.

Answer (score 3):

There is an [official SendGrid Apex helper library](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-apex) that is also open source if you need to modify it or don't wan't to use the unmanaged package.

Raising an issue there would be a good starting point if something isn't working as expected.

Answer (score 2):

[Harvest Solutions has an app](http://www.harvestsolutions.net/harvest-email-plus) that provides a set of APIs to send emails from Salesforce via Amazon SES.  They support attachments as well.  As you might know, the multi-part MIIME is the harder bit.  I dont think that is supported with Send Grid.

Comment: I haven't seen this message before, interesting. Will get in touch with this provider to understand better their implementation.

Answer (score 1):

[Zapier](https://zapier.com/zapbook/amazon-ses/salesforce/) provides an integration between Amazon SES and Salesforce. I have never used it, so I can't vouch for it. However, I've heard of success stories using Zapier, which is designed to make integrations like these easier.

Answer (score 0):

Hi The app you are talking about is MassMailer. Its an unlisted app because sendgrid is not giving security support.It works perfectly and is the best solution for MassMailing. If you need any assistance regarding setup or demo let me know.

Here is the link to the app in app exchange

https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000005uxj5EAA

If anyone needs to contact me please mail me at saiba.sharma@mansasys.com